# ParcelJS v2 less error: Inline JavaScript is not enabled. Is it set in your options?

Tags: node.js, less, parcel, parceljs

I'm trying to run `parcel watch` on some files which use rsuite dependency but always end up getting this error:

```
@parcel/transformer-less: Inline JavaScript is not enabled. Is it set in your options?
```

I already tried installing older versions of `less`, adding a .lessrc file with `javascriptEnabled` option set to `true`, installing `parcel-plugin-less-js-enabled` but still no progress.

Could anyone please help me with this?

Comment: I can't repro this with the newly-released parcel `2.0.0`. If it's still a problem for you, would you mind sharing a minimal reproduction?